# How to recursivelly delete all files with certain name with FileZilla

Tags: ftp, ftp-client, filezilla

I would like to know how can I delete files in bulk with FileZilla.

One of my websites have been hacked, and I know that they introduced an `info.html` file in almost all my WordPress folders.

So my question is, if there is a way to bulk delete all the files with the name `info.html` from all the folders and subfolders of my WordPress installation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use *Server > Search remote files* command to find a list of the files.

Use a rule like:
*Filename* > *is equal to* > `info.html`

Then in *Results* pane, select all found files using <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>, right click the selection and click *Delete*.

Comment: This is an *excellent* way to delete files with a certain filename extension.  Using: Filename > ends with > .jpg